# Converting a value into a wait time gauge(cool down gauge)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have run into a wall recently, as a newish programmer I don't know how get over it.

This is code:

```
 public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float minDuration = 1.5f;
    public float maxDuration = 5f;
    public float minValue = 1f;
    public float maxValue = 99f;
    public float currentValue;
    public float waittime;
    public float EVA;
    public Image Waitgauge;



    void Start()
    {
        waittime = Mathf.Round(GetDurationRemaining(minDuration, maxDuration, minValue, maxValue, currentValue) * 10f) / 10f;
        EVA = Evasion(currentValue);
    }




    private void Update()
    { /*
        UpgradeWaitGauge();
        */
    }




    public float GetDurationRemaining(float minDuration, float maxDuration, float minValue, float maxValue, float currentValue)
    {
        float durationGap = maxDuration - minDuration;
        float t = Mathf.InverseLerp(minValue, maxValue, currentValue);

        //Sine easing - Change this equation to match a curve you'd like
        t = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * t * 0.5f);

        return minDuration + ((1f - t) * durationGap);
    }




    /*
     void  UpgradeWaitGauge()
    {
        waittime += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 origScale = Waitgauge.transform.localScale;
        origScale.x = Mathf.Clamp(waittime / (waittime - maxDuration), 0, 1);
        Waitgauge.transform.localScale = origScale;
    }
    */





    public float Evasion(float CurrentValue)
    {
        return Mathf.Round((currentValue * 0.30f) *100f / 100f);
    }
}
```

I am creating a wait gauge similar to ones found in the video games series Final Fantasy (4-9,12). What this code does is give a wait time, till the next turn, based on the speed value, which is currently just called "currentValue". If you take the code as is and go into the inspector, you can put a value in the "currentValue" and it returns a wait time. This works the way that I want it too.

If you look in the code I have commented out the "Upgrade waitgauge function" because that is where the problem is happening. I would like to take the wait time and represent it visually, as a gauge that fills to full based on the returned wait time:

if a wait time of 2.5 secs is returned then it will take 2.5 secs for the bar to fill.

If a wait time of 4.7 secs it returned then it will take 4.7 secs to fill.

I would like to also mention that the wait gauge will always remain the same size.

I worked on this for 11 hours trying to figure it out my last day off. Pretty frustrating because I actually got this to work with a practice code, but the speed formula for that was much simpler. Assistance is badly needed.

Comment: `current/total` -> alpha cutoff value or slider bar value?

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z7_ZbNUNw8) shows you how to create a simple health bar. The reason I'm linking this is because you can use the same concept for creating your timer gauges. You just need to adjust the FillAmount of the image to correlate to the `current/total` time as Draco18s mentioned above.

Comment: I already have the health bar up and ready. Current time/total was the first thing I thought, because that is what I used in my original attempt and it worked. If I do that now, what happens is the gauge will be already filled the difference between the current and total time and fill from there. Not what I am looking for.